# Non Standard Characters in User Names

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies, display-names

While browsing M.SE, I came along this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282768/how-to-solve-x-5x#comment617117_282768).

Out of curiosity I tried to put a comment-reply. Copy-paste is working (this time), but can't we have an autocompletion right after the @?

BTW: Which characters are allowed in user names? I got [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1139/19341), saying that $\LaTeX$ won't be rendered.

Would an @ be allowed? I thought about giving it a try, but I fear that comment replies won't work anymore since only 1 @ seems to be allowed in a comment, see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/7149/19341) for some experiments.

Comment: But "אליהו צלע" is perfectly standard... :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila depending on your reference system that's true. To make one thing clear, this isn't not meant in any offending way at all...

Comment: Oh, I was poking fun at all you folks who don't speak fluent Hebrew.:-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila מַצְחִיק , I hope that's not wrong...

Comment: It's correct...

Comment: I should probably add that the autocompletion works fine if you type in Hebrew letters.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I should look out for user with ä,ö,ü or ß in the username and give it a try. Is hebrew written from right to left?

Comment: Yes, it is a right to left text (which makes almost all text editing annoying as hell).

Comment: Hi guys, how's it going?

Comment: @ℝⁿ. Not bad. You do realize that you are stuck with this username for 30 days, right?

Comment: @5PM: That is a burden I am willing to $\require{enclose}\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\text{bear}}$impose on everyone who wants to reply to me. (Sorry...)

Comment: @Rahul: Moderators can override this, if I recall correctly. Just flag this question and ask for your name to be set again.

Comment: @Asaf: oh heck no. I want to see him suffer. `:-)`

Comment: BTW, I can verify that if you know how to type ℝ in unicode (I use the LaTeX input method plugin for [iBus](http://code.google.com/p/ibus/wiki/LaTeX)), autocompletion for @ℝⁿ.also works.

Comment: @Asaf: just want to double check, for the autocompletion on hebrew names, do I need to start typing from the right-most character first?

Comment: @Willie: Yes. א is the first letter of that user name.

Comment: I just realized that there is an additional **not** in my first comment. Please disreagrd it...

Comment: @ℝⁿ. The new autocomplete-with-nonASCII feature automatically brings up your username. [So there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/168155).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/49331/206169) Atwood specified the allowed  username format as `^[\w](?<!_)`, and helpfully added the image below. If I understand correctly, `(?<!_)` prohibits usernames beginning with an underscore.

By the way, the userpage URL stays within ASCII. Some non-ASCII characters like é are [converted to ASCII](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url), others are simply dropped.

[image: allowed characters]